# Error from rails console with .new

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is the error message in rails production console. User is a model and the error is created by "a = User.new".

```
D:\rails_proj\emclab-failed>rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> a = User.new
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSHOW TABLES←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (10.0ms)←[0m  describe `users`
SyntaxError: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:83:in `module_eval'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:83:in `define_read_method'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:42:in `define_method_attribute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:35:in `define_method_attribute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:291:in `block in define_attribute_method'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:286:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:286:in `define_attribute_method'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:282:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:282:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:282:in `define_attribute_methods'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:14:in `define_attribute_methods'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:65:in `respond_to?'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:103:in `read_attribute'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1774:in `attribute_for_inspect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1891:in `block in inspect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1889:in `collect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1889:in `inspect'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0>
```

However the same command in development generates a new instance without any error. The difference is that there is no data in production database. It is sqlite3 for development and mysql 5.1.54 for production.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> a = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, salt: nil, status: "active", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_type: nil>
```

Any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code for read.rb?

Comment: Does the error happen on describe or on 'new'?

Comment: it is on new. See error attached. read.rb is part of rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gem are you using for mysql? According to [this issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1050) you may just need to run `bundle update mysql2` if you're using the mysql2 gem.

Comment: So you are still getting the same error? If so, 1) did you mean to accept this answer as correct? 2) When you ran 'bundle update' did it update the mysql2 version?